# Можете пожалуйста объяснить,что надо сделать в задании

Tags: лингвистика

можете пожалуйста объяснить,что надо сделать в задании:к данным трем словам (предложены понятия и имена, ставшие нарицательными)  приведите пример-иллюстрацию:  Митрофанушка, хлестаковщина, Плюшкин .

Answer (score 2):

Обычно примером-иллюстрацией называют пример употребления слова в речи, например: "Отец - форменный Плюшкин - не дал денег дочери даже на дорогу".

Comment: В принципе можно, если Вам было задано придумать контекст. А то можно и готовые примеры употребления поискать.

Comment: а не поможете со словом хлестаковщина, а то у меня только со словом хлестаков  получается придумать